# Trying to make the second and so forth buttons working like the first button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, button

I manage to get the first button to run depend on the Target Value and Input Value. Then with Arithematic operator control, the button will turn red or green. But my second and so forth buttons is not working. I'm not sure how to code differently to make the following buttons work like the first button. 
I know it is a bad practice to duplicate similar code over and over again as I have 31 buttons.

Please help

```js
// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn1 = document.getElementById('b1');
// When the user clicks on the button, open the modal 
btn1.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";}
var btn2 = document.getElementById('b2');
btn2.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";}
var btn3 = document.getElementById('b3');
btn3.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";}
var btn4 = document.getElementById('b4'); 
btn4.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";}
var btn5 = document.getElementById('b5'); 
btn5.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";}
var btn6 = document.getElementById('b6'); 
btn6.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";}
var btn7 = document.getElementById('b7'); 
btn7.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";}
var btn8 = document.getElementById('b8'); 
btn8.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";}
var btn9 = document.getElementById('b9'); 
btn9.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";}
var btn10 = document.getElementById('b10'); 
btn10.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";}
var btn11 = document.getElementById('b11'); 
btn11.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";}
var btn11 = document.getElementById('b12'); 
btn11.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";}
var btn11 = document.getElementById('b13'); 
btn11.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";}
var btn11 = document.getElementById('b14'); 
btn11.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";}
var btn11 = document.getElementById('b15'); 
btn11.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";}
var btn11 = document.getElementById('b16'); 
btn11.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";}
var btn11 = document.getElementById('b17'); 
btn11.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";}

// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}
// Get the Reset
var reset = document.getElementById('ResetModal');

var rst = document.getElementById('reset'); 
rst.onclick = function() {
    reset.style.display = "block";}

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span1 = document.getElementsByClassName("close1")[0];

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span1.onclick = function() {
    reset.style.display = "none";
}
// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == reset) {
        reset.style.display = "none";
    }
}
//Arithematic Operator Control
// For Button 1
var target_value = document.getElementById('inputtarget');
function checkValue(){
  var inputvalue = document.getElementById('modal1');
  var buttonsubmit = document.getElementById('b1');
  var value = parseInt(inputvalue.value);
  var targetValue = parseInt(target_value.value);
  
  if (value < targetValue){
    buttonsubmit.style.background = 'red' ;
    buttonsubmit.innerText = value ;
  }
  else if (value >= targetValue){
    buttonsubmit.style.background = 'green';
    buttonsubmit.innerText = value ;
  }
  else{
    buttonsubmit.style.background = '';
    buttonsubmit.innerText = '1';
  }
  modal.style.display = "none" ;
  return false;
}
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  background-color: yellow;
  height:580px;
  Width:290px;
  text-align: 0 auto:
}

#b1,#b2,#b3,#b4,#b5,#b6,
#b7,#b8,#b9,#b10,#b11,#b12,
#b13,#b14,#b15,#b16, #b17, #b18,
#b19,#b20,#b21,#b22, #b23, #b24, 
#b25,#b26,#b27,#b28, #b29, #b30, #b31 {
  background-color: rgb(211,211,211);
  height:50px;
  width: 50px;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-weight: bold;
  box-shadow: 0 1px #999;
}
#b30, #b31{
background-color: rgb(211,211,211);
  height:50px;
  width: 25px;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-weight: bold;
  box-shadow: 0 1px #999;
}
#inputtarget {
  height: 60px;
  width: 100px;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1;
}
#b1:hover, #b2:hover, #b3:hover, #b4:hover, 
#b5:hover, #b6:hover, #b7:hover, #b8:hover, 
#b9:hover, #b10:hover, #b11:hover, #b12:hover,
#b13:hover, #b14:hover, #b15:hover, #b16:hover,
#b17:hover, #b18:hover, #b19:hover, #b20:hover,
#b21:hover, #b22:hover, #b23:hover, #b24:hover,
#b25:hover, #b26:hover, #b27:hover, #b28:hover,
#b29:hover, #b30:hover, #b31:hover {
  background-color: grey;
}
#b1:active, #b2:active, #b3:active, 
#b4:active, #b5:active, #b6:active, 
#b7:active, #b8:active, #b9:active, 
#b10:active, #b11:active, #b12:active, 
#b13:active, #b14:active, #b15:active, 
#b16:active, #b17:active, #b18:active, 
#b19:active, #b20:active, #b21:active, 
#b22:active, #b23:active, #b24:active, 
#b25:active, #b26:active, #b27:active, 
#b28:active, #b29:active, #b30:active, #b31:active {
  background-color: silver;
  box-shadow: 1px #666;
  transform: translateY(2px);
}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content/Box */
.modal-content {
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: 15% auto; /* 15% from the top and centered */
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 240px;
    height: 200px;
}
#modal1 {
  height:70px;
  width:100px;
  text-align: center;
}
/* The Close Button */
.close {
    color: #aaa;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

/* Reset (background) */
.reset {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Reset Content/Box */
.reset-content {
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: 15% auto; /* 15% from the top and centered */
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 240px;
    height: 200px;
}
#resetyes, #resetno {
  height:70px;
  width:100px;
  text-align: center;
}
/* The Close Button */
.close1 {
    color: #aaa;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.close1:hover,
.close1:focus {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
<div>
  
<!-- All Buttons in Matrix Form Production -->
  <button id="b1" style="position:absolute; left:30px; top:100px">1</button>
  <button id="b2" style="position:absolute; left:80px; top:100px">2</button>
  <button id="b3" style="position:absolute; left:130px; top:100px">3</button>
  <button id="b4" style="position:absolute; left:180px; top:100px">4</button>
  <button id="b5" style="position:absolute; left:30px; top:150px">5</button>
  <button id="b6" style="position:absolute; left:80px; top:150px">6</button>
  <button id="b7" style="position:absolute; left:130px; top:150px">7</button>
  <button id="b8" style="position:absolute; left:180px; top:150px">8</button>
  <button id="b9" style="position:absolute; left:230px; top:150px">9</button>
  <button id="b10" style="position:absolute; left:30px; top:200px">10</button>
  <button id="b11" style="position:absolute; left:80px; top:200px">11</button>
  <button id="b12" style="position:absolute; left:230px; top:200px">12</button>
  <button id="b13" style="position:absolute; left:30px; top:250px">13</button>
  <button id="b14" style="position:absolute; left:80px; top:250px">14</button>
  <button id="b15" style="position:absolute; left:230px; top:250px">15</button>
  <button id="b16" style="position:absolute; left:30px; top:300px">16</button>
  <button id="b17" style="position:absolute; left:80px; top:300px">17</button>
  <button id="b18" style="position:absolute; left:130px; top:300px">18</button>
  <button id="b19" style="position:absolute; left:180px; top:300px">19</button>
  <button id="b20" style="position:absolute; left:230px; top:300px">20</button>
  <button id="b21" style="position:absolute; left:30px; top:350px">21</button>
  <button id="b22" style="position:absolute; left:80px; top:350px">22</button>
  <button id="b23" style="position:absolute; left:130px; top:350px">23</button>
  <button id="b24" style="position:absolute; left:180px; top:350px">24</button>
  <button id="b25" style="position:absolute; left:30px; top:400px">25</button>
  <button id="b26" style="position:absolute; left:80px; top:400px">26</button>
  <button id="b27" style="position:absolute; left:30px; top:450px">27</button>
  <button id="b28" style="position:absolute; left:80px; top:450px">28</button>
  <button id="b29" style="position:absolute; left:30px; top:500px">29</button>
  <button id="b30" style="position:absolute; left:80px; top:500px">30</button>
  <button id="b31" style="position:absolute; left:105px; top:500px">31</button>
  <p style="position:absolute; left:175px; top:410px; font-size:20px; 
            font-weight:bold">TARGET</p>
  <input id="inputtarget" type="number" ondrop="returnfalse;" onpaste="returnfalse;" 
           onkeypress='return event.charCode>=48 && event.charCode<=57';
         style="position:absolute; left:165px; top:460px"><br>
  <button id="reset" style="position:absolute; left:30px; top: 60px">Reset</button>
</div>

<!-- The Modal Box 1-->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p>PLEASE INPUT QUANTITY</p>
    <input id=modal1 type="number" ondrop="returnfalse;" onpaste="returnfalse;" 
           onkeypress='return event.charCode>=48 && event.charCode<=57'; 
           style=font-size:20px><br>
    <br>
    <button id="submit" onclick= "return checkValue()" >SUBMIT</button>
  </div>
  
<!-- The Reset Box -->
<div id="ResetModal" class="reset">
  <!-- Reset content -->
  <div class="reset-content">
    <span class="close1">&times;</span>
    <p>Are you sure ?  <br>
       This Action cannot be undone.</p>
    <input id=resetyes type="button" value="YES">
    <input id=resetno type="button" value="NO">
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Holy cow dude.  Put a class on those buttons and bind your click logic to the class.  That's a crazy amount of duplicate code you got there at the start of your script.

Comment: Sorry, i'm new with these languages

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It is hard to follow this example because of all the duplication. Consider trying to reproduce in a [minimal viable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), perhaps with only two buttons.

Answer (score 0):

this should help you!

The main thing is, I'm `setting` id as attribute on `target_value` button in button event loop,, here:

```
// Each button click => open modal 
for(var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++){
  btns[i].onclick = function() { 
    TV.setAttribute('startbtn', this.id );
    modal.style.display = "block"; 
  }
}
```

and then I'm getting it in checkValue() function, like this:

```
var buttonsubmit = document.getElementById( TV.getAttribute('startbtn') );
```

So that, basically, replaces hardcoding that manual targeting as you had on start of your script.

hth, cheers!

```js
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
// Get the button that opens the modal
var btns = document.querySelectorAll('button:not([id=reset]):not([id=submit])');
// Get the Reset
var reset = document.getElementById('ResetModal');
var rst = document.getElementById('reset'); 
// target value
var TV = document.getElementById('inputtarget');
rst.onclick = function() {
    reset.style.display = "block";}
// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span1 = document.getElementsByClassName("close1")[0];
// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span1.onclick = function() {
    reset.style.display = "none";
}
// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == reset) {
        reset.style.display = "none";
    }
}
// Each button click => open modal 
for(var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++){
  btns[i].onclick = function() { 
    TV.setAttribute('startbtn', this.id );
    modal.style.display = "block"; 
  }
}
// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}
//Arithematic Operator Control
// For Button 1
function checkValue(){
  var inputvalue = document.getElementById('modal');
  var buttonsubmit = document.getElementById( TV.getAttribute('startbtn') );
  var value = parseInt(inputvalue.value);
  var targetValue = parseInt(TV.value);
  
  if (value < targetValue){
    buttonsubmit.style.background = 'red' ;
    buttonsubmit.innerText = value ;
  }
  else if (value >= targetValue){
    buttonsubmit.style.background = 'green';
    buttonsubmit.innerText = value ;
  }
  else{
    buttonsubmit.style.background = '';
    buttonsubmit.innerText = '1';
  }
  modal.style.display = "none" ;
  return false;
}
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 580px;
  Width: 290px;
  text-align: 0 auto:
}

#b1,
#b2,
#b3,
#b4,
#b5,
#b6,
#b7,
#b8,
#b9,
#b10,
#b11,
#b12,
#b13,
#b14,
#b15,
#b16,
#b17,
#b18,
#b19,
#b20,
#b21,
#b22,
#b23,
#b24,
#b25,
#b26,
#b27,
#b28,
#b29,
#b30,
#b31 {
  background-color: rgb(211, 211, 211);
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-weight: bold;
  box-shadow: 0 1px #999;
}

#b30,
#b31 {
  background-color: rgb(211, 211, 211);
  height: 50px;
  width: 25px;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-weight: bold;
  box-shadow: 0 1px #999;
}

#inputtarget {
  height: 60px;
  width: 100px;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1;
}

#b1:hover,
#b2:hover,
#b3:hover,
#b4:hover,
#b5:hover,
#b6:hover,
#b7:hover,
#b8:hover,
#b9:hover,
#b10:hover,
#b11:hover,
#b12:hover,
#b13:hover,
#b14:hover,
#b15:hover,
#b16:hover,
#b17:hover,
#b18:hover,
#b19:hover,
#b20:hover,
#b21:hover,
#b22:hover,
#b23:hover,
#b24:hover,
#b25:hover,
#b26:hover,
#b27:hover,
#b28:hover,
#b29:hover,
#b30:hover,
#b31:hover {
  background-color: grey;
}

#b1:active,
#b2:active,
#b3:active,
#b4:active,
#b5:active,
#b6:active,
#b7:active,
#b8:active,
#b9:active,
#b10:active,
#b11:active,
#b12:active,
#b13:active,
#b14:active,
#b15:active,
#b16:active,
#b17:active,
#b18:active,
#b19:active,
#b20:active,
#b21:active,
#b22:active,
#b23:active,
#b24:active,
#b25:active,
#b26:active,
#b27:active,
#b28:active,
#b29:active,
#b30:active,
#b31:active {
  background-color: silver;
  box-shadow: 1px #666;
  transform: translateY(2px);
}


/* The Modal (background) */

.modal {
  display: none;
  /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed;
  /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1;
  /* Sit on top */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Full width */
  height: 100%;
  /* Full height */
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  /* Black w/ opacity */
}


/* Modal Content/Box */

.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: 15% auto;
  /* 15% from the top and centered */
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 240px;
  height: 200px;
}

#modal1 {
  height: 70px;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}


/* The Close Button */

.close {
  color: #aaa;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* Reset (background) */

.reset {
  display: none;
  /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed;
  /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1;
  /* Sit on top */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Full width */
  height: 100%;
  /* Full height */
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  /* Black w/ opacity */
}


/* Reset Content/Box */

.reset-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: 15% auto;
  /* 15% from the top and centered */
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 240px;
  height: 200px;
}

#resetyes,
#resetno {
  height: 70px;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}


/* The Close Button */

.close1 {
  color: #aaa;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close1:hover,
.close1:focus {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- All Buttons in Matrix Form Production -->
<button id="b1" style="position:absolute; left:30px; top:100px">1</button>
<button id="b2" style="position:absolute; left:80px; top:100px">2</button>
<button id="b3" style="position:absolute; left:130px; top:100px">3</button>
<button id="b4" style="position:absolute; left:180px; top:100px">4</button>
<button id="b5" style="position:absolute; left:30px; top:150px">5</button>
<button id="b6" style="position:absolute; left:80px; top:150px">6</button>
<button id="b7" style="position:absolute; left:130px; top:150px">7</button>
<button id="b8" style="position:absolute; left:180px; top:150px">8</button>
<button id="b9" style="position:absolute; left:230px; top:150px">9</button>
<button id="b10" style="position:absolute; left:30px; top:200px">10</button>
<button id="b11" style="position:absolute; left:80px; top:200px">11</button>
<button id="b12" style="position:absolute; left:230px; top:200px">12</button>
<button id="b13" style="position:absolute; left:30px; top:250px">13</button>
<button id="b14" style="position:absolute; left:80px; top:250px">14</button>
<button id="b15" style="position:absolute; left:230px; top:250px">15</button>
<button id="b16" style="position:absolute; left:30px; top:300px">16</button>
<button id="b17" style="position:absolute; left:80px; top:300px">17</button>
<button id="b18" style="position:absolute; left:130px; top:300px">18</button>
<button id="b19" style="position:absolute; left:180px; top:300px">19</button>
<button id="b20" style="position:absolute; left:230px; top:300px">20</button>
<button id="b21" style="position:absolute; left:30px; top:350px">21</button>
<button id="b22" style="position:absolute; left:80px; top:350px">22</button>
<button id="b23" style="position:absolute; left:130px; top:350px">23</button>
<button id="b24" style="position:absolute; left:180px; top:350px">24</button>
<button id="b25" style="position:absolute; left:30px; top:400px">25</button>
<button id="b26" style="position:absolute; left:80px; top:400px">26</button>
<button id="b27" style="position:absolute; left:30px; top:450px">27</button>
<button id="b28" style="position:absolute; left:80px; top:450px">28</button>
<button id="b29" style="position:absolute; left:30px; top:500px">29</button>
<button id="b30" style="position:absolute; left:80px; top:500px">30</button>
<button id="b31" style="position:absolute; left:105px; top:500px">31</button>
<p style="position:absolute; left:175px; top:410px; font-size:20px; 
            font-weight:bold">TARGET</p>
<input id="inputtarget" type="number" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;" onkeypress='return event.charCode>=48 && event.charCode<=57' ; style="position:absolute; left:165px; top:460px"><br>
<button id="reset" style="position:absolute; left:30px; top: 60px">Reset</button>
</div>

<!-- The Modal Box 1-->
<div id="myModal" class="modal" >

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p>PLEASE INPUT QUANTITY</p>
    <input id="modal" type="number" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;" onkeypress='return event.charCode>=48 && event.charCode<=57' ; style=font-size:20px><br>
    <br>
    <button id="submit" onclick="return checkValue()">SUBMIT</button>
  </div>

  <!-- The Reset Box -->
  <div id="ResetModal" class="reset">
    <!-- Reset content -->
    <div class="reset-content">
      <span class="close1">&times;</span>
      <p>Are you sure ? <br> This Action cannot be undone.</p>
      <input id=resetyes type="button" value="YES">
      <input id=resetno type="button" value="NO">
    </div>
```

Comment: HI Kresimir,
Something is not right with the modal. Numeric Buttons should only open "myModal" and Reset Buttons should only open "ResetModal".
Right now, Numeric Buttons are openning both "MyModal" and "ResetModal"